# Is there a way I can interact with realtimedatabase from dialogflow fulfillment

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es, chatbot, hangouts-api

Just getting started with dialogflow and programming. I am developing a dialogflow chatbot.

Is there a way of getting data from realtime database via dialogflow fulfillment codes? I want the agent to return an answer if the user's input matches a question. I am thinking the code loops through the question column and where there is a match it returns the corresponding answer column.

Don't know if this is correct. Any assistance or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Code samples would go a long way. Thank you.

The integration is with Hangouts.